Get everything in quotes from a variable in a cmd batch file
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _n=Inspecting "Leisure Suit Larry" - setup data version 5.6.2
set _n=!_n:*"=!
set _n=!_n:"*=!

echo !_n!

Output: Leisure Suit Larry" - setup data version 5.6.2
Expected: Leisure Suit Larry
Am I missing something stupid with this command? set _n=!_n:"*=!
Shouldn't it remove the last quote and everything after it??
btw, it's in a for loop.
Thanks.
update: The variable which comes from a file name has a ')' in it... does that affect it?

You can't use * after a character the same way that you can use it before one, but you can tokenize on quotes and grab the second token.
That said, because the for /f options typically needs to be written in quotes, you have to do some weird escaping to specify " as the actual delimiter.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _n=Inspecting "Leisure Suit Larry" - setup data version 5.6.2

for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%A in ("%_n%") do set "name=%%A"
echo !name!


Thanks but I'm not using a for /f for file contents, I'm just getting the file name.

The quotes inside of the parentheses tell the for loop that it's processing a string, not a file.

The help for command SET output on running set /? in a command prompt window explains which string substitutions are possible. set VAR=%VAR:*STR=% or with enabled delayed variable expansion set VAR=!VAR:*STR=! for replacing everything up to end of first occurrence of STR by an empty string is supported by the command SET. But there is no syntax for replacing everything from beginning of STR to end of the string value assigned to an environment variable by an empty string. Something like set VAR=%VAR:STR*=% replaces case-insensitive all occurrences of STR* by an empty string.
Let us assume the current working directory on execution of the batch file contains a file with name List File.txt with the following lines:
Inspecting "Leisure Suit Larry" - setup data version 5.6.2
Other line with "Development & Test 100% (!)" (line 2)
"Line 3 with double quoted text at beginning" on a line containing something else too
One more line with no double quoted text
Hello world"
;"Sixth line with text in quotes"

The batch file should output on execution:
Leisure Suit Larry
Development & Test 100% (!)
Line 3 with double quoted text at beginning
Sixth line with text in quotes

The following batch file produces that output:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if exist "List File.txt" for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("List File.txt") do (
    set "Line=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "Line=!Line:"=#!"
    if not "!Line!" == "!Line:#=!" (
        set "Line=!Line:*#=!"
        if defined Line (
            for /F delims^=#^ eol^= %%Q in ("!Line!") do endlocal & echo(%%Q
        ) else endlocal
    ) else endlocal
)
endlocal

Note: The character # in the command lines above must be an ASCII character which for sure does not exist in file List File.txt and is not "*<>|~. I used in the batch file for testing the character DEL with decimal byte value 127 (hexadecimal 7F). The character DEL has no glyph and is not displayed for that reason by a web browser which is the reason why the lines above contain the character # instead of the character DEL.
The other FOR /F loop processes the lines in file List File.txt in the current working directory which can be any directory and is not necessarily the directory containing the batch file. There can be used twice "%~dp0List File.txt" instead of just "List File.txt" for referencing this text file with full path of the batch file directory.
Empty lines are skipped by FOR /F. All other lines are by default split up into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters which results in removing also all leading spaces/tabs. The line is ignored by default if the first substring begins with default end of line character ;. The first substring is assigned otherwise to the specified loop variable. That line splitting behavior is changed by passing the options usebackq delims= eol= to FOR /F for instructing it interpreting the string in " as text file name (usebackq) of which lines should be processed and an empty list of delimiters (delims=) for turning off the line splitting behavior and no end of line character (eol=) for not ignoring any non-empty line. eol= must be the last option in this special case. The options cannot be enclosed in " as otherwise " would be interpreted as end of line character. It is therefore necessary to escape each space and equal sign with the character ^ for getting them interpreted literally and not as argument string separators by cmd.exe on parsing the command line before execution of the cmd internal command for. Each non-empty line read from the text file is assigned as is first to the specified loop variable L and next to the environment variable Line one after the other during the FOR loop iterations.
Now delayed variable expansion is enabled in the loop. It cannot be enabled before as otherwise a text file name without or with path containing one or more ! could not be correct processed at all. Delayed variable expansion cannot be enabled before execution of set "Line=%%L" as otherwise this line would be parsed a second time by cmd.exe after replacing %%L by the line string read from the file and interpreting now ! as beginning/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference resulting in an unwanted modification of the string assigned to the environment variable Line.
There are next replaced all " in the line assigned to the environment variable Line by a different single byte per character encoded character with no special meaning for cmd.exe on (double) parsing a command line and for sure not existing in the text file.
The IF condition compares case-sensitive the resulting string assigned to the environment variable Line with the string produced on removal of all replacement characters which means the removal of all " from the line read from the text file. The line does not contain any text enclosed in " if the two strings are identical in which case just the command endlocal is executed to restore the previous environment with disabled delayed variable expansion.
There is removed otherwise from the string assigned to the environment variable Line everything up to first occurrence of the replacement character which means everything up to first occurrence of " in line read from the text file using a string substitution.
That can result in assigning an empty string to the environment variable Line if a line contains just one " at the end of the line like on fifth line with Hello world". In this case just the previous environment is restored with disabled delayed variable expansion as the environment variable Line is not defined anymore with a string to process further.
The resulting string is processed otherwise with one more FOR /F loop which splits up the string into substrings using the specified delimiter character and no end of line character and assigns just the first substring to the specified loop variable Q. That is the string up to second " in line read from the file or everything up to end of the line if there is no second " in the line after first ".
The previous environment with disabled delayed variable expansion is restored first and next the string assigned to the loop variable Q is output which can contain now even characters like !&()<>|. The string assigned to loop variable Q is not parsed a second time before execution of command echo. But this string can consist of just spaces/tabs and can begin also with /? which is the reason why echo( instead of echo  is used to output the string assigned to the loop variable Q instead of output of current status of command echo mode or the usage help of command ECHO.
To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

echo /?
endlocal /?
for /?
if /?
set /?
setlocal /?

See also:

Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file explaining the meaning of the unconditional command operator & on not being inside a double quoted argument string.
DosTips forum topic ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/ for the detailed description why using echo( is best on output of a unknown string.
This answer for details about the commands SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL and what happens in background on each execution of these two commands.


This works here, in a single replacement...
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _n=Inspecting "Leisure Suit Larry" - setup data version 5.6.2

set "_n=!_n:*"=!

echo !_n!

However, the correct replacement depends on the value that appears after the last quote, so this may fail in certain cases...

wow, excellent. i don't know how it works with only this: set "_n=!_n:*"=! but this is great! thanks :)

@AllenGray, in order to see how this works, just execute it with echo on
